# Pegar link contido em um script JS

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar uma função que localiza e coloque o valor de um link contido em uma javascript em uma variável para outra função utilizar essa variável mais tarde.

Vamos ao exemplo real:

O código está contido dento de uma TAG "script" pertencente a um "iframe". Código do iframe:

```html
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/163969741?autoplay=true" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Preciso localizar dentro desse "iframe" a seguinte informação:

```js
{"profile":164,"width":640,"mime":"video/mp4","fps":30,"url":"https://gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1507047701~acl=%2A%2F519593631.mp4%2A~hmac=781e23a73042594f4bf64f28d21e5c59171367a3bbcf0753a578d2be56cbd7e9/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/2793/6/163969741/519593631.mp4","cdn":"akamai_interconnect","quality":"360p","id":519593631,"origin":"gcs","height":360}
```

E depois tratar essa informação para que fique somente o:

```
https://gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1507047701~acl=%2A%2F519593631.mp4%2A~hmac=781e23a73042594f4bf64f28d21e5c59171367a3bbcf0753a578d2be56cbd7e9/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/2793/6/163969741/519593631.mp4
```

Esse é o site para onde o verdadeiro iframe está: https://www.comofaz.com.br/video/como-calcular-limites

Comment: Se o vimeo não tiver CORS autorizado/aberto não podes aceder ao conteúdo dessa iframe.

Comment: Hum.. podes confirmar isso para mim por favor?

Comment: Lembrando que eu só capaz de selecionar o link do vídeo de forma manual, porém gostaria de fazer isso automaticamente se possível, assim como fiz com OpenLoad.co a um tempo atras.

Comment: Esse código HTML da iframe é gerado por ti? ou por um `embeded`?

Comment: Ele ta sendo gerado pela pagina que botei no final do post. É um site de tutorias em video.

Comment: Vc nao consegue fazer nada com um iframe de outro dominio via JS. Vc conseguiria fazer isso com PHP ou ASP, por exemplo.

Comment: Como ficaria em php então?